# Migrating Adobe Livecycle to AEM Forms

Tags: aem, livecycle

I have a requirement from one of my friend's firm where he wants to migrate from his Adobe Livecycle workflow based form management to AEM forms. Since there is an end of support planned for Livecycle, the migration needs to be quick and also there is a need for scalability.
So this is the ask in specific, existing is a cluster installation running Livecycle ES3 and need to go to 6.3.

I could see that the upgrade path suggested by Adobe is ES3->ES4->AEM6.1->AEM6.3. This is both lengthy and costly. Is there a manual route that can allow the migration to happen directly. May be like I can create the two clusters and then somehow take the assets out of livecycle into the AEM forms and thing start working?
If yes, then what is the scope of effort I am seeing here, like first setting up the 6.3 then probably taking a dump of assets (what all assets that need to be migrated) and what to do with Livecycle assets in AEM 6.3 to make it work?

Any quick support will be helpful. And I really hope this is the right forum for asking this question, in case not please advise the correct place and I would most happily move the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer is that it depends on what LiveCycle ES3 modules are installed.  Most of the ES3 modules do not store production data that needs to be migrated so you may not need to follow the upgrade path you’ve outlined.  The two modules that *do* store data are the Process Management and Rights Management modules.  If your friend is using either of these two modules, then there is data in their production system that probably needs to be migrated (and you therefore have to go through the ES3->ES4->AEM6.1->AEM6.3 upgrade process).

If they are not using either of the “Management” modules, then you should be able to export your application to a .LCA from ES3 and then re-import the application into AEM 6.3.

If you have issues importing the .LCA, then it’s also possible to import the processes manually by unzipping the .LCA and dragging the .process files from the filesystem into AEM 6.3  workbench however you usually have to fix up any internal linkages between processes and sub-processes when you do this.

The company I work for, [4Point](http://www.4point.com/), specializes in LiveCycle/AEM consulting and 
we have lots of experience migrating customers from earlier versions of LiveCycle to the latest versions of AEM.  Have your friend’s firm contact us if they need assistance in performing the migration.  We’ve done lots of these kinds of migrations and know what to expect.

Comment: With process management, you'll also get away without doing a DB upgrade if you only have short lived processes or if you don't care about keeping historical process information.

Comment: While I consider both of these scenarios unlikely, I’ve also seen them both, so they’re by no means unheard of.  I would add the following caveats:If you’re only using short-lived processes, I would not install Process Management the next time around as you’re not actually using it.  Also, in the second scenario, where you don’t care about historical data, you also have to not have (or not care about) any processes in progress as you’ll lose those if/when you do a fresh install unless you plan to keep the old and new instances running in parallel until processes on the old instance complete.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe now provides a direct upgrade path from LiveCycle ES4 to AEM 6.3 Forms. You can setup a new AEM 6.3 Forms server and use the import/export route for upgrade.